# Parse JSON data with Apache Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

[image: Click here to see Image]

I have this type of file with data where each line is a JSON object except first few words(see attached image). I want to parse this type of file using Spark and Scala. I have tried it using sqlContext.read.json(“path to json file”) but it gives me error(corrupt data) because whole data is not a JSON object. How do I parse this JSON file to SQL dataframe?

Comment: If you have invalid JSON, you can't parse it using any tool

Comment: is this invalid JSON?

Comment: Well, the fact that you have non JSON data before the actual JSON, then yes, it's not valid in Sparks eyes. You need to extract that data separately

Comment: is there any way in Spark to extract data separately?

Comment: @AkhilChoudhari is these "first few words" have the same length in all rows?

Comment: @semsorock yes, it has same length in all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
val rawRdd = sc.textFile("path-to-the-file")
val jsonRdd = rawRdd.map(_.substring(32)) //32 - number of first characters to ignore

val df = spark.read.json(jsonRdd)
```

Comment: Last command gave me an error shown below.
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)

Comment: it would be easier if you could provide some example data to test.

Comment: what version of spark do  you use?

Comment: When I provide whole 20MB file to spark.jso.read(), its not working. but its working for half of the file. why?

Comment: It gives me error that :
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: